# How to Export javascript 2D and Area line chart with javascript using PHP

Tags: php, fusioncharts

Here is the code that i use

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                            // this function exports chart from JavaScript
                            function exportChart(exportFormat)
                            {
                                // checks if exportChart function is present and call exportChart function
                                if ( FusionCharts("myChartId3").exportChart )
                                    FusionCharts("myChartId3").exportChart( { "exportFormat" : exportFormat } );
                                else
                                    alert ( "Please wait till the chart completes rendering..." );

                            }


                        </script>
            <input value="Export to JPG" type="button" onClick="JavaScript:exportChart('JPG')" />
                        <input value="Export to PNG" type="button" onClick="JavaScript:exportChart('PNG')" />
                        <input value="Export to PDF" type="button" onClick="JavaScript:exportChart('PDF')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        var myChart3 = new FusionCharts("FusionCharts/FCF_Line.swf", "myChartId3", "730", "440","0","1"); 
        myChart3.setDataURL("data.php?<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>"); 
       myChart3.render("chartdiv3");    
</script>
```

Comment: Is there an error? What is happening with the code above?

Comment: yes i can not export my graph it alerts   alert ( "Please wait till the chart completes rendering..." );

Comment: Where is FusionCharts being defined? It's failing the check if the function is present. Did you include the js file?

Comment: yes i include the js and i get the graph too but i cannot export it properly. <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/FusionCharts.js"></SCRIPT> this is the script which i include in the top of the page

Comment: Is the path being translated correctly and you're absolutely sure the .js file is loading? Use Chrome and hit Control+Shift+J to bring up the error console and hit the page. See what javascript errors you are receiving.

Comment: yes the path is correct I got the graph In my xml file there was a <chart> tag in the documentation but in my xml file there is <graph> tag is that differs? thanks

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts Free does not support exporting the charts as Images/PDF. To export the charts as images, make use of SWF files from FusionCharts XT.

Download the latest version at: http://www.fusioncharts.com/download/trials/